# Move mail to folder from button on ribbon

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that will run perfectly using F8 to step through it but will skip the last step, to move an email, when run from a button on the ribbon.

Here is the code.

```
Sub Reportmail()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Move As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim selEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim moveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MItem As MailItem

    'Append subject & Move
    For Each MItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        MItem.Subject = "Suspicious Email: " & MItem.Subject
    Next
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    On Error GoTo xyz
    Set myNewFolder = olFolder.Folders.Add("Suspicious Items")

    xyz:
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Suspicious Items")
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set folder to move suspicious email into
    Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Suspicious Items")
 
    'SET Task
    Set selEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Forward
    'Set Recipient
    selEmail.Recipients.Add "myemail@mydonain.com"
    'Send Email
    selEmail.Send

    'Move email to folder
    ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Move objDestFolder   
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by last step?  Last line or the `xyz:`

Comment: Last Line. It will not move the email to the Suspicious Items Folder when run from a button on the ribbon.

Comment: I think much depends upon how many messages comprise your "selection" object, and that the index numbers for individual items in a collection can change as your code processes those items.

I'd recommend first setting up your folder objects, then iterating and handling each message in your `For Each MItem` loop. If you've only got one message selected when you step through your code, but more than one when you test your button, the number of messages selected could be the difference instead of the button-vs-F8 issue.

Comment: I'll add that I think your code only moves/forwards the first message in your selection, regardless of how many you've selected?

Comment: it is intended to only move 1 message at a time.

Comment: So if the selection is 3 messages, you change the subjects of all three, but only move one, leaving the other 2 in your inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd show what I tried to explain in my comment to your question:

```
    'Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    'Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set objNS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
'****I'd prefer condensing above to the following since olApp, objNS not used again
    Set olFolder = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    On Error Resume Next '<-****my personal preference, part 1
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Suspicious Items")
    On Error GoTo 0 '<--- updated per comments
'xyz: <-****my personal preference, part 2. Nothing "wrong" with how you wrote it.
    If olFolder.Name = "Inbox" Then Set olFolder = olFolder.Add("Suspicious Items")
    
'****objNS and olFolder already defined!! No need to set 2 objects to same folder.
    'Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set folder to move suspicious email into
    'Set objDestFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Suspicious Items")
 
    'SET Task
    'Append subject & Move
    For Each MItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        MItem.Subject = "Suspicious Email: " & MItem.Subject
        Set selEmail = MItem.Forward
        'Set Recipient
        selEmail.Recipients.Add "myemail@mydonain.com"
        'Send Email
        selEmail.Send
        'Move email to folder
        'MItem.Move objDestFolder
        MItem.Move olFolder
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly now. I knew my sloppy coding had something to do with it.

Comment: Missing `On Error GoTo 0` after `Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Suspicious Items")`.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks, @niton

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the problem by adding error trapping and examining the error message and the variables' values at the time of the error by adding:

```
    On Error GoTo oops
    {your code}
finish:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
oops:
    Debug.Print Err.Number;Err.Description
    Debug.Assert False
    Resume finish
End Sub
```